# getline vs istream_iterator

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

Should there be a reason to preffer either getline or istream_iterator  if you are doing line by line input from a file(reading the line into a string, for tokenization).

Comment: You've kind of answered the question yourself - use `getline` to get a line, or `istream_iterator` for tokenisation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I sometimes (depending on the situation) write a line class so I can use `istream_iterator`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct Line
{
    std::string lineData;

    operator std::string() const
    {
        return lineData;
    }
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str,Line& data)
{
    std::getline(str,data.lineData);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
     std::vector<std::string>    lines(std::istream_iterator<Line>(std::cin),
                                       std::istream_iterator<Line>());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`getline` will get you the entire line, whereas `istream_iterator<std::string>` will give you individual words (separated by whitespace).

Depends on what you are trying to accomplish, if you are asking which is better (tokenization is just one bit, e.g. if you are expecting a well formed program and you expect to interpret it, it may be better to read in entire lines...)

Comment: Sorry I should have added that the line is comma seperated. so istream_iterator<string> would in fact fetch the entire line.

Comment: If you do no expect the input to be malformed _EVER_, which is a difficult thing to say, yes, you will get an entire line.

Comment: Each cell on a line must not contain spaces either.

Comment: This is not entirely correct, you can use an overloaded getline to read up to the first user specified token (default is a newline)

Answer (score 0):

@Martin York's answer-- while works-- fails in many areas when used with STL's algorithm. A simpler solution is to use inheritance.

```
struct line : public std::string{
    using std::string::string;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, line& l){
    std::getline(s, l);
    return s;
}
```